# XCTest Conditional response

Tags: xctest, xctestexpectation

My app is a quiz.  Responses required can be for:
1. Responses to questions - 5 possible answers
2. OK to prompt "Correct Answer"
3. OK to prompt "Wrong Answer"
4. OK to prompt "Game Level is "
5. OK to prompt "Game over"

I have recorded the responses and have now built the following:

```
let okButton = app.alerts["Correct Answer"].buttons["OK"]
        let okButton2 = app.alerts["Wrong Answer"].buttons["OK"]
        let okButton01 = app.alerts[" \n\n\n \nGame Level is 1\n\n\n\n"].buttons["OK"]
        let okButton02 = app.alerts[" \n\n\n \nGame Level is 2\n\n\n\n"].buttons["OK"]
        let okButton03 = app.alerts[" \n\n\n \nGame Level is 3\n\n\n\n"].buttons["OK"]
        let okButton04 = app.alerts["UKNew£1Coin\n\n\n \nGame Level is 4\n\n\n\n"].buttons["OK"]
        let restartButton = app.alerts["Game Over\nCongratulations\n\nRestarting Game"].buttons["OK"]
```

Responses are as follows:

for index in 1...100 {

```
    twoElement.tap()
    okButton.tap()
    okButton2.tap()
    okButton01.tap()
    okButton02.tap()
    okButton03.tap()
    okButton04.tap()
    restartButton.tap()

}
```

What I would like is to either put an if statement or a switch case statement

Writing

```
if twoElement.tap(){
twoElement.tap() }
```

does not work

as for the switch, I do not know what should be the value against which the different values of same type will be compared

Anyone has done something similar successfully, please?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You say you want a switch statement or similar, but not what you hope to achieve. Please add more info to the question.

Comment: Changed the code to:   if oneElement.exists
            {
                oneElement.tap()
            }
it works